# Where does this backBarButtonItem come from again?

Tags: uinavigationcontroller, pushviewcontroller, backbarbuttonitem

I have a UINavigationController (A) which has a few subviews which also are UIViewControllers (B and C).  The main UINavigationController (A) rides inside of a UITabViewController (D).

I'm trying to push a view controller within B:
`[self.navigationController pushViewController... etc]`

Now, the backBarButtonItem comes through with the wrong text.  Instead of saying 'Back', it just says 'Item'.  This is likely because one of the view controllers in my chain has its title set to 'Item' or maybe it is nil altogether.

My question is, where is the backBarButtonItem generated from?

I tried a few different things that didn't work.  I tried each of these lines of code within B right before I pushed the view controller.  None of them worked.

`self.presentingViewController.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"... etc`

`self.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"... etc`

`self.navigationController.backBarButtonItem = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Back"... etc`

I'd like to learn the principle here so that I truly understand where this item is being populated from and what the right way to do it is.

Comment: Is there a navigation controller involved?  If so, where?  Which view controllers are children of the navigation controller?  Which view controller is the parent of the navigation controller, or is it the window's root view controller?

Comment: My bad, I fixed it and referenced the UINavigationController where it is in the chain.  Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let's say your `C` controller is on top of the navigation controller's stack, and your `B` controller is under that.  E.g.

```
navigationController.viewControllers = @[ bViewController, cViewController ];
```

So the navigation controller is displaying `cViewController.view`.

The navigation controller uses the second-to-top controller on its stack to configure the back button. In this case, it uses `bViewController` to configure the back button. This is its algorithm:

```
UINavigationItem *navigationItem = bViewController.navigationItem;
UIBarButtonItem *barItem = navigationItem.backBarButtonItem;

if (barItem.image != nil) {
    show a back button containing barItem.image;
}

else if (barItem.title != nil) {
    if (barItem.title.length > 0) {
        show a back button containing barItem.title;
    } else {
        don't show a back button;
    }
}

else if (navigationItem.title != nil) {
    if (navigationItem.title.length > 0) {
        show a back button containing navigationItem.title;
    } else {
        don't show a back button;
    }
}

else {
    show a back button containing @"Back";
}
```